# MYSQL Query select only first record of foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, I am pretty new to MySQL. I am currently stuck with the following query. I have several tables that have relations between each other. Every user can create multiple projects. Every project can have one attachment, multiple attachments (images) or no attachment at all. Every project only has one user.

**Table users**

| id | username | avatar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | image1.png |
| 2 | user2 | image2.png |

**Table projects**

| id | title | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | project1 | 1 |
| 2 | project2 | 1 |

**Table images**

| id | image_name | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | attachment1.png | 1 |
| 2 | attachment2.png | 1 |

My current query:

```
SELECT 
    projects.id,
    projects.title,
    users.username,
    users.avatar,
    images.image_name
FROM
    users,
    projects,
    images
WHERE
    users.id = user_id
        AND projects.id = project_id
```

This gives me the following output:

| id | title | username | avatar | image_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | project1 | user1 | image1.png | attachment1.png |
| 1 | project1 | user1 | image1.png | attachment2.png |

This query only selects projects that are related to an image. Projects that do not have an image are not selected.  I would like to select all existing projects. Also, I would like to select only one row per project. Meaning, I would like to either select only the first related image or build up multiple image-columns per project (if this is possbile - otherwise only the first image entry).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proper joins so that you can play around with LEFT or RIGHT JOI

So you can use

Also add row_number a window function added in mysql 8 will help selecting the right images

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `username` VARCHAR(5),
>   `avatar` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO users
>   (`id`, `username`, `avatar`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'user1', 'image1.png'),
>   ('2', 'user2', 'image2.png');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE projects (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `title` VARCHAR(8),
>   `user_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO projects
>   (`id`, `title`, `user_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'project1', '1'),
>   ('2', 'project2', '1');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE images (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `image_name` VARCHAR(15),
>   `project_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO images
>   (`id`, `image_name`, `project_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'attachment1.png', '1'),
>   ('2', 'attachment2.png', '1');
> ```

> ```
>     SELECT 
>         p.id,
>         p.title,
>         u.username,
>         u.avatar,
>         i.image_name
>     FROM
>         users u INNER JOIN 
>         projects p 
>         ON u.id = p.user_id
>         LEFT JOIN 
>         (SELECT `id`, `image_name`, `project_id`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `project_id` ORDER BY `id`) As rn FROM images )  i ON p.id = i.project_id and rn = 1
>     WHERE
>        u.id = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title    | username | avatar     | image_name     
> -: | :------- | :------- | :--------- | :--------------
>  1 | project1 | user1    | image1.png | attachment1.png
>  2 | project2 | user1    | image1.png | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1bf71b9354b2c7382875b9b6fd6dad7)*

## mysql 5.7 Version

> ```
>     SELECT 
>         p.id,
>         p.title,
>         u.username,
>         u.avatar,
>         i.image_name
>     FROM
>         users u INNER JOIN 
>         projects p 
>         ON u.id = p.user_id
>         LEFT JOIN 
>          images   i ON p.id = i.project_id and i.id = (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM images WHERE project_id = i.project_id)
>     WHERE
>        u.id = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title    | username | avatar     | image_name     
> -: | :------- | :------- | :--------- | :--------------
>  1 | project1 | user1    | image1.png | attachment1.png
>  2 | project2 | user1    | image1.png | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dee202b860312948697e7a8a1ca13341)*

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked very well for displaying all projects. However, it still selects every image related to a projects and hence produces more then one row for each project if a project has more than one image. Is there a way to resolve this and select only one row per project (selecting only the first image per project and neglecting the others)?

Comment: which myslq version do you have 5.x or 8?

Comment: i change it to a mysql 8 version

Comment: I´m using mysql 5.x

Comment: It did work though, thank you very much!!

Comment: i added a version for mys1ol 5

Answer (score 0):

You should use join with on clause. This makes your query much more readable.

```
 SELECT 
    P.id,
    p.title,
    u.username,
    u.avatar,
    GROUP_CONCAT(i.image_name)
 FROM
     projects p
 INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id
 LEFT JOIN images i ON i.project_id = p.id
```

Comment: After adding a Group By this worked very well, thank you!